# placeholders inside plugin template not showing up - djangocms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to render placeholders inside the plugin template. flow should be: users add a plugin into already existing placeholder in base.html and inside that rendered plugin template, there should be another placeholders for text and image.

I googled some but could not find a proper solution. is there anyone with same experience?

Comment: Please add some code to help others help you.

Comment: Show your plugin code & template(s)